# About some properties of composites of field extesions

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

When I'm self-studying  Parick Morandi's book Field and Galois Theory,I came across some problems,which I can't work out fully. Let $K$, $L$, be two extension fields of base field $F$. If  $K/F$ and $L/F$ are both Galois extension ,how to proof that their composite $KL$ is also Galois over $F$. And why we have the same conclusion when "Galois "is replaced by "normal","separable","purely inseparable",or "algebraic"? I worked on these problems and searched this website  for two days but could only proof the cases for "separable","purely inseparable",and "algebraic".I have no idea how to proof the "normal" and "Galois" cases. In addition ,why the degree inequality  holds for $$ [KL:F]\leq[K:F][L:F]$$
If you know how to proof these ,please tell me.I am here waiting for the answers.Thank you!

Comment: Actually if the "normal" case is right,then the “Galois " case follows since Galois extension is precisely normal and separable extension and the "separable "case I have proven.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already know how to prove the *separable* case, and a field extension is galois if it is finite, separable, and normal, so it remains to prove the *normal* case.
First notice that, if a field extension $L/F$ is generated by elements $x_i$ such that all conjugates of $x_i$ are inside $L,$ then $L/F$ is normal by linearity. Then observe that, if $B_1:=\{x_1,\cdots,x_n\}$ is a basis for $L/F,$ and $B_2:=\{y_1,\cdots,y_m\}$ a basis for $K/F,$ then $\{x_iy_j|i=1,\cdots,n, j=1,\cdots,m\}$ generates $KL/F.$
For the degree inequality, it is also explained by the fact that $\{x_iy_j|i=1,\cdots,n, j=1,\cdots,m\}$ generates $LK/F$ if $B_i$ is a generating set for $i=1,2.$
I think this is enough to prove the proposition, if something is confusing, inappropriate, or wrong, please inform me, thanks.

Comment: I'm not so sure that : $\{x_iy_j|i=1,\cdots,n, j=1,\cdots,m\}$ is a basis for $KL/F.$@awllower

Comment: @王李远 Thanks, that set only generates $KL/F,$ which suffices for our purpose here.

Comment: I know that  $\{x_iy_j|i=1,\cdots,n, j=1,\cdots,m\}$ generates  $KL/F$, but this doesn't mean that they are a basis. For example ,for the extension $Q( \sqrt[3]{2},\omega)/Q$, $\sqrt[3]{2}$,$\omega $ generates the field ,but not a basis.

Comment: Yes ,it is suffices.but how about the  degree inequality@awllower

Comment: In fact, if an extension $F/K$ is generated by $n$ elements, then $\left[F:K\right]\le n,$ so the generation of $KL/F$ by $nm$ elements suffices for that inequality. Also, I did not claim the set being a basis now.

Comment: $Q(\sqrt[3]{2})$ is generated by one element, but $[Q\sqrt[3]{2}:Q]=3$ @awllower

Comment: Sorry, I mean *generated as a vector space*, not as a ring. So $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]2)$ is generated by three elements.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39629/discussion-between--and-awllower).

Comment: I can't distinguish when a generating set can be viewed as a generating set of vector space,can you explain that .I am confused now.

Comment: When I say that a field extension is generated by elements $x_i,$ I mean that the extension viewed as a vector space is generated by $x_i.$ If I want to say *generated* as rings, I would state it explicitly.